# How do I test a existing gradle.build with gradletestkit?

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit5, gradle-task

I want to load a `build.gradle` file into gradle testkit and using Junit 5 so that I can test the buildscript inside build.gradle

The exaple in the manual only show how you write and test in the code and with Junit4

My Test classs looks like this

```
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.BuildResult;
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder;


import static org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome.*;

public class BuildLogicFunctionalTest {

    private Project project;
    private ProjectBuilder projectbuild;
    @TempDir 
    private File projectfile;



    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldTask() throws IOException {

        projectbuild = ProjectBuilder.builder();
        project = projectbuild.build();

        BuildResult result = GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(project.getBuildDir())
            .withArguments("helloWorld")
            .build();

        assertTrue(result.getOutput().contains("Hello world!"));
        assertEquals(SUCCESS, result.task(":helloWorld").getOutcome());
    }
}
```

The Testkit build script looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies { 
    testImplementation gradleTestKit()
    implemenation localGroovy()
    implementation gradleApi()
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2'
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.0'
}
```

The build.gradle file that I want to test looks like this

```
task helloWorld {
        doLast {
            println 'Hello world!'
        }
}
```

How do I load the build.gradle into the program?

How should the GradleRunner code look like to test the task helloWorl?

Answer (score 3):

TestKit requires you to put your Gradle configuration files into the given project directory. You'll see in [this example test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#example_using_gradlerunner_with_junit) that a new `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` are created for the test.

Aside, this tool is primarily intended for testing custom tasks and Gradle plugins. I get the sense that you're trying to use it to test your root `build.gradle` script. This is risky because the test engine may modify the contents of the directory passed to `withProjectDir(...)` and modify or delete your sources.

I recommend you follow [this Gradle guide](https://guides.gradle.org/testing-gradle-plugins/) to learn more about testing your build logic.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution looks like this:

```
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.BuildResult;
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer;


import static org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome.*;

public class BuildLogicFunctionalTest {




    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldTask() throws IOException {
        File projectdir = new File("/Users/stein/Development/ReactSpringBooTutorial/todoapp")



        BuildResult result = GradleRunner.create()
        .withProjectDir(projectdir. getAbsoluteFile())
        .withArguments("helloWorld")
        .build();



        assertTrue(result.getOutput().contains("Hello world!"));
        assertEquals(SUCCESS, result.task(":helloWorld").getOutcome());
    }
```